# python + selenium: send multiline text to input

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on a text game for a live chat. First, I ask a question. Second, I scrape the answers and handle a player score. It works. But after each 30 questions I want to print a player score table like this:

```
| no | player.......... | score | words |
-----------------------------------------
| .1 | player 1........ | ..174 | ...36 |
| .2 | player 2........ | ..147 | ...48 |
| .3 | player 3........ | ..115 | ...33 |
```

to this element `<input class="some_class" value="">` So I need somehow to include new line characters and trick / force the driver (maybe some javascript ?) to not discard them. I think it should be possible to do it somehow because: 1) I saw someone to successfully post ASCII art image - message to this chat and that image was not broken. 2) also when I go to this page https://yaytext.com/bold-italic/ and type multiline text, then copy it and paste it to the live chat, the input window is properly resized, which I consider to be the step in the right direction. But of course when I hit the submit button, the message is posted without newlines.

UPDATE 30.12.2020:
I have just one more idea/question: As I wrote before I can copy and paste "line 1\n line2" to `<input>` element which will cause that this box is resized accordingly. But After I hit submit button, the new line is gone. So my question is: what exactly is responsible for eating that new line? Is it chromedriver? If so, chromedriver is opensource, so would be possible just modify the chromedriver source so that it will not eat new line and compile my own modified chromedriver?

Comment: Please provide the code to show what you have tried already.

Comment: Your code trials?

Comment: @koder613 I just tried to use standard newline "line 1\nline 2" which of course did not work.